# Why $R_n \simeq R_p \times R_q$ if $pq = n$ and $gcd(p, q) =1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Why $R_n \simeq R_p \times R_q$ if $pq = n$ and $gcd(p, q) =1,$ and where $R_x$ is a cyclic group of order $x.$

I think that is because $\mbox{lcm} (p, q) = pq$ and so if we start from $(1,1)$ then to get to next $(1,1)$ we need to go through $pq$ values, and so we can define isomorphism somehow.

But this is proof is not really cool, can you give me a cool proof with using cool words like `cyclic group`, `direct product` and so on. Thanks.

Comment: What is $R_{n}$, $R_{p}$, $R_{q}$? Cyclic groups of order $n$, $p$, and $q$, respectively? Might want to a define these objects in order to get good feedback.

Comment: @Oiler thanks! changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyclic groups are uniquely determined up to isomorphism by their order. So since $|R_n| = |R_p\times R_q|$ (since $pq=n$), it suffices to show that $R_p\times R_q$ is cyclic $\Leftrightarrow gcd(p,q) = 1$. Proof is below:

$(\Rightarrow)$
Assume that $gcd(p,q)\neq1$ then we can find integers $k > 1, p_1 < p, q_1 < q$ with $p = p_1k$ and $q=q_1k$. Now let $(x,y)\in R_p\times R_q \Rightarrow x^p = e$ and $y^q = e \Rightarrow (x,y)^{p_1kq_1} = (x^{(p_1k)q_1},y^{(q_1k)p_1}) =(e,e)$. Thus no element has order $pq$ (since $p_1kq_1 < pq$) so $R_p\times R_q$ is not cyclic.

$(\Leftarrow)$
As you suggested consider $(x,y)$ where $x, y$ are generators of $R_p, R_q$, respectively.  Let $n_o$ be the order of $(x,y)\Rightarrow$

$(x^{n_0},y^{n_0}) = (e,e)$.  $\hspace{1in}$   (1)

Since $|x| = p$ and $|y| = q$ this means that $n_0$ is a multiple of $p$ and $q$. You can see that any common multiple of $p,q$ will satisfy (1). Therefore, the order will be the least common multiple.

Since $lcm(p,q) = \frac{pq}{gcd(p,q)}$ and $gcd(p,q)=1$, we get that the order of $(x,y)$ is $pq$ and so the group is cyclic.